# What free git diff GUI can I use on MacOS Big Sur?

Tags: git, macos, macos-big-sur

I am attempting to do a git diff on macOS Big Sur, and much of the apps I would use on Windows or Linux (e.g. Meld, Kdiff3, etc), don't seem to be operable anymore under BigSur perhaps because the are no longer trusted.

```
“Meld.app” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.
```

Any idea what open source / free programs I can use there to visualize my diffs ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. Questions asking us to find or recommend an off-site resource like a tool are explicitly _off-topic_ as they tend to attract opinion-based answers and spam.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Github offers this GUI for MacOS

[Github GUI for MacOS](https://desktop.github.com/)

Xcode also installs utilities you can use from the command line, e.g.

```
git diff
```

Comment: Thank  you, this works for my purposes because I'm starting with a local repo. Not sure if you can push to anywhere  else other  than Github

Comment: I believe the App works against the local repo, not the remote. So, it does NOT matter where you push to. It will show you the diff locally which is probably what you want anyway.